# WooCommerce checkout custom checkbox value not returning value when unchecked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created an additional checkbox in the WooCommerce checkout which is successfully returning the value 'Yes' when it is checked. However, if it is not checked, there is no value being returned. This is the code I am trying:

```
// PRICE MATCH GUARANTEE OPT-IN
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes' , 'sab_price_match_guarantee', 10, 1 );
function sab_price_match_guarantee( $checkout ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'pricematch_policy', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'label'         => __('Yes, I would like to opt-in.'),
        'required'      => false,
    ),  $checkout->get_value( 'pricematch_policy' ));     
}

// PRICE MATCH - Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'sab_pricematch_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );
function sab_pricematch_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['pricematch_policy']) && ! empty($_POST['pricematch_policy']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'pricematch_policy', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pricematch_policy'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No') );
    } 
}

// PRICE MATCH - Display optin on the order edit page/my account pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'sab_display_pricematch', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', 'sab_display_pricematch', 10, 1 );
function sab_display_pricematch( $order ) {
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Price Match Guarantee Opt-In').':</strong> ' . $order->get_meta('pricematch_policy') . '</p>'; 
}
```

This is the line of code I am trying to get working:

```
$order->update_meta_data( 'pricematch_policy', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pricematch_policy'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No') );
```

How can I return the value 'No' if the checkbox is not checked? Appreciate everyone's advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: Checkboxes only send when checked, if you always want to receive a value switch to a radio or select with the default value preselected.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if the checkbox is unchecked then its value will not be available in form data. hence, you'll have to do only `isset` validation for true and false. Also, you should not save the value as **Yes** or **No** because if you do this then `$checkout->get_value( 'pricematch_policy' )` will not match with `1` in the `woocommerce_form_field` function. so save the value as `1` or `0` and then during the print, you print the values conditionally.

Otherwise, save the value as `Yes` or `No` and in `woocommerce_form_field` pass the value in form of `1` or `0`

To save the checkbox value, you'll have to use this code.

```
$order->update_meta_data( 'pricematch_policy', isset( $_POST['pricematch_policy'] ) ? 1 : 0 );
```